# ios Xcode images.xcassets issue (deleted image keeps showing)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image

1. I had an image in images.xcassets that I was using for my launch screen. I deleted the image, but the image keeps showing up when I use the same file name. For instance, the actual file with "Logo.png" doesn't exist anywhere, and when I type in "Logo" for the image view, the Interface Builder shows a question mark, but when the app is launched, the image shows perfectly fine.
2. The new image I'm trying to use doesn't show up when it's loaded from images.xcassets. The new image file is not corrupt because when I just embed it in the project, not the xcassets file, it loads just fine.

This is the stupidest and most frustrating issue I ever had. Does anyone have a clue?

*Update: For some reason it suddenly works now. I didn't do a thing...

Comment: not able to analyse your doubt. make it clear

Comment: delete the app from your simulator and try again

Comment: I tried deleting the app, deleting the derived data, cleaning, everything, and it didn't work. But for some reason it's working all of a sudden. Way to waste an hour an a half pulling out my hair...

Comment: And now the problem is back. What the heck. Seriously...